# Python 3.6: No module named '_sqlite3'

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I have two versions of python running 2.7 and 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.02

Using Python 2.7, the below code will run successfully.

```
# will compile successfully
import sqlite3
```

But when using Python 3.7, the below code will throw - No module named _sqlite3 error.

```
# will throw no module error
import sqlite3
```

Is there any solution to this problem?
[image]

Comment: How did you install Python 3.6? You need to re-compile the extension modules after installing the libsqlite3-dev headers.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters :)